# How do I create one coin at the time-phaser3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm making a game with phaser3 and I want to make it so that when the player punches the other character it drops a coin if it has coins.
However when I punch the character it drops multiple coins. 
Here's the code:

```
function punchplayer2(player, player2) {
  if (punching == true)
    if (score2 > 0) {
      coin = this.physics.add.sprite(player2.x, player2.y - 40, "coin");
    }
}
```

Well I left some parts out and left the important part.
How do I make it, so the character only drops one coin, instead of many coins?

Comment: You can try and add some `console.log()` to see what's causing, from this piece of code it's hard to say why that's happening.

Comment: I added console.log("1"); to the code and then it said down (the key to hit) and 1 three times which means three coins were created after pressing down once.

Comment: Where exactly did you add that `console.log()`? In any case, it appears that that `punchplayer2()` is being called at least 3x

Comment: I added it after if (score2 > 0) {

Comment: Yes, so it seems that `punchplayer2()` is being called at least 3x, you'll have to trace back and see how that is happening as it does seem you want that function called only once.

Comment: I've looked at phaser3 docs and it seems that there is an alternative to cursors called checkDown(key [, duration]). Maybe I could use that and have the character punch after the key is pressed every 5 seconds or so. I'm not sure how to implement it though.

Comment: Hard to help as there's not enough code, if you were able to create a jsfiddle or publish your code somewhere then we could have a better understanding of what's happening.

Comment: here's my github https://github.com/peteblank/dog I can't put it on jsfiddle because the game has assets. Thank you.

Comment: When I run your code, I get "Cannot read property 'checkDown' of undefined". I think what you want is `cursors.down.isDown` rather than `Phaser.Key.checkDown("16", "3000"))`. Also, when I "punch" the other dog, I don't see the `"1" in the logs, are you sure the code in github is up to date? Please fork this https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-leaf-2xvly?file=/index.html

Comment: Thank you, I was just trying to change cursors.down.isDown to Phaser.Key.checkdown and see if that worked. Sorry about that. But I changed the code to the one you posted and it still has the same issue.